# Where is the "Advanced" button relating to this Firefox security error?

Tags: firefox, certificate

https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/01/06/man-in-the-middle-interfering-with-increased-security/

> How to tell if you’re affected
>
> If you can access this article in Firefox, you’re fine.  If you’re reading this in another browser, see if you can load the security blog (or any other HTTPS link) in Firefox.  Click “Advanced”, and if you see the error code “SEC_ERROR_CERT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM_DISABLED”, then you’re affected.

I don't understand the instructions. Where is 'Advanced'? I can't find it.

Comment: I suspect this means on the error page itself.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you haven't got the error page is why you can't see the button. To be honest, I think they meant to write "Technical Details" instead of "Advanced", as per this page:

[image: Error page]

As you didn't receive that page, you have nothing to worry about, as the instruction states:

> **If you can access this article in Firefox, you’re fine.**  If you’re reading this in another browser, see if you can load the security blog
>   (or any other HTTPS link) in Firefox.  Click “Advanced”, and if you
>   see the error code “SEC_ERROR_CERT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM_DISABLED”, then
>   you’re affected.

Thanks to @Burgi for providing an example of this security error in Chrome - where interestingly the button to click *is* Advanced:

[image: Chrome Sec Error]

Comment: I was busy making my own screenshots to answer this :)

Comment: @Burgi Whoops, sorry ! :)

Comment: Here is the Chrome version if you want to add it to your answer: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FvezP.png